# findViewById in static method in different class

Tags: android, static-methods, findviewbyid

Inside on of my android fragments I have the following simple check as to whether my app runs on a tablet or not (on a tablet I have 3 views open, view 2 and 3 are not seen on a phone, only the first one is seen)

```
boolean mDualPane;
View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.content1);
mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
```

This works fine in the fragment itself, but I need the exact same check in many fragments and so I wanted to have it in my "MiscMethods" class that I use for frequently used methods in multiple classes. Now the same cod in my class looks like this:

```
public class MiscMethods{    
public static boolean landscapeChecker(){
    boolean mDualPane;
    View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.content1);
    mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    return mDualPane;   
}
}
```

getActivity (and if I delete that findViewById) is undefined for the type MiscMethods.

Now I have an Application class for context like here

```
public static void ErrorToast(int errorCode) {
    String errorString = null;
    switch (errorCode) {
    case 1:
        errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_tooManyFieldsEmpty);
        break;
    case 2:
        errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_featureComingSoon);
        break;
    case 3:
        errorString = App.getContext().getString(R.string.error_SwitchBreak);
        break;
    default:
        errorString="Wrong Error Code";
        break;
    }
    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    errormsg.show();
}
```

but this App.getContext() also does not help.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're searching for a quick-and-dirty solution, so here are two:

- Change the method signature's to take the activity as a parameter:

  `public static boolean landscapeChecker(Activity activity)`.

  In the method, use the passed-in `activity` in place of `getActivity()`. Call it from your various activities like `boolean mDualPane = landscapeChecker(this)`.
- Subclass `Activity` and put the method there instead. For this solution, you would create a class `MyActivity extends Activity`, then make your various activities `extend MyActivity` instead of `extend Activity`. In the method, use `this` in place of `getActivity()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first solution works perfectly, although since it's fragments i  need landscapeChecker(getActivity()); THANKS SO MUCH :)

Answer (score 0):

you just declare on MainActivity static element before oncreate .
   after this  create a metod on bottom;

```
static TextView textView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....................................................

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texview);
}

public static void upTex(String up) {


        textView.setText(up);
    }


}

//other file class
public class other{

   public void method(){
     upText("jaja");
 }
```