# findviewbyid not working in public static class android java

Tags: java, android, static-classes

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            EditText dob = findViewById(R.id.dob);
        }
    }
    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
```

I want to put the value I got from user into the EditText in `"OnDataSet"` Function And The `findviewbyid` There Is Giving Me Error

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have not type casted it to EditText.
EditText dob = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);

Answer (score 1):

if you want `findviewById` in **static** you shoul call `rootView`

```
rootView.findViewById
```

**
For ease of work you can use this library [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

and for more information :

1. [findviewbyid-inside-a-static-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342004/findviewbyid-inside-a-static-method)
2. [findviewbyid-in-static-method-in-different-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700588/findviewbyid-in-static-method-in-different-class)
3. [findviewbyid-not-working-in-static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671608/findviewbyid-not-working-in-static-function/38671622)

Comment: your welcome , and remember ButterKnife is very good library

Answer (score 1):

**Here Is The Answer Which I Have Written**

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            EditText dob = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dob);
            dob.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
        }
    }
```

**Changes In onDateSet**

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    EditText dob = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dob);
    dob.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
}
```